# Data not passing from popup to background in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I think I got the hang of it but it's just not working... and I can't figure out why.

Manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Dummy Extension",
  "description": "Dummy Extension Description",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Dummy Extension",
     "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "jquery.min.js", "background.js" ],
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
  }]
}
```

Background:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener( function(request,sender,sendResponse)
{
    if( request.greeting === "GetURL" )
    {
        var tabURL = "Not set yet";
        chrome.tabs.query({active:true},function(tabs){
            if(tabs.length === 0) {
                sendResponse({});
                return;
            }
            tabURL = tabs[0].url;
            sendResponse( {navURL:tabURL} );
        });        
    }
}
```

Popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src='popup.js'></script>
<script src='jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    Hello World!
        <br />
    <input id="tabURL" type="text" />
        <br />
    <input value="SEND!" type="button" id="send" />
</body>
</html>
```

And popup.js

```
function getURL() {
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({greeting: "GetURL"},
        function (response) {
            tabURL = response.navURL;
            $("#tabURL").val(tabURL);
        });
}

$("#send").click(getURL());
```

I just can't figure out whats wrong, jquery is defined, I get no console errors.
Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#send").click(getURL());` gets executed before DOM is fully constructed and fails. Also, you need to pass the reference to `getURL`, not execute it.

To fix:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#send").click(getURL);
});
```

By the way, you may be looking in the wrong console for errors. See [this debugging tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) for popups.

Comment: You'll have to refine your response and replace `click(getURL())` with `click(getURL)`

Comment: @devnull69 Thanks, didn't notice that